# How do you reference (in your document) enumerated items listed in your reference list?

Tags: cross-referencing

How do you reference (in your document) enumerated items listed in your reference list? i.e. I have the code:

```
~\ref{itm:ref1}
```

In the body of my document and:

```
\label{itm:ref1}
```

In my reference list after my first reference. For some reason (that I hope you'll explain to me) this doesn't suffice in helping me back-reference the first item in my reference list.

For additional information or clarification this is how the section with my `~\ref` tag in it looks:

```
\section*{Symptoms: Influenza}
The flu has the following symptoms:~\ref{itm:ref1}
```

Whereas in my reference list, I have:

```
\section*{References}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{BETTER HEALTH CHANNEL, 'Flu (influenza)', \textit{Better Health Channel} [web page] (2012), \hyperref{http://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/bhcv2/bhcarticles.nsf/pages/flu_influenza?open}{}{}{Flu (influenza)}, accessed 10 Mar. 2013.}
\label{itm:ref1}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use `bibtex` to manage your references? This would make your live waaaaaay easier.

Comment: Here you can read an introduction to bibliographies in LaTeX. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management -- I recommend `biblatex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are automatic ways to create bibliographies using `bibtex` or `biblatex`.  However, sometimes in a small document, some people prefer to do this "by hand".  The mechanism provided by LaTeX is

- `\cite` instead of `\ref`
- `thebibliography` instead of a `enumerate` and the heading, and
- `\bibitem` instead of `\item`

Using this your example would be:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section*{Symptoms: Influenza}
The flu has the following symptoms:~\cite{ref1}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ref1} BETTER HEALTH CHANNEL, 'Flu (influenza)',
  \textit{Better Health Channel} [web page] (2012),
  \hyperref{http://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/bhcv2/bhcarticles.nsf/pages/flu_influenza?open}{}{}{Flu (influenza)}, accessed 10 Mar. 2013.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The argument to `\bibitem` corresponds to the label, and is the key used in `\cite`.

Note the argument `{9}` to the bibliography environment, this is a placeholder indicating the widest label.  If you have between `10` and `99` `\bibitems` it should be set to `{99}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{itm:ref1} First item 
\item\label{itm:ref2} Second  item 
\end{enumerate}
In ~\ref{itm:ref1} and ~\ref{itm:ref2} ...
\end{document}
```